# How to call a JavaFX class from another class?

Tags: javafx

In my project I have 3 files:

**FXMLController.java** this is a JavaFX file

**FXML.fxml** this is another JavaFX file

**JavaApplication3.java** This file just contains my main method:

```
public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        Application.launch(FXMLController.class);
    }

}
```

I want to launch my FXMLController class from my main method to run the program. How to do it ? My code I have written is not working maybe because I have this error "no suitable method found for launch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller is created when you load the FXML file which specifies its class. A JavaFX application must be started using a subclass of [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html). You should really think of the `start()` method in `Application` as being the equivalent of a main method in a regular Java application:

```
import javafx.application.Application ;
import javafx.stage.Stage ;
import javafx.scene.Scene ;
import javafx.scene.Parent ;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader ;

import java.io.IOException ;


public class JavaApplication3 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // for the benefit of environments that don't support direct launch
    // of JavaFX Applications:

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This assumes:

1. The structure of your FXML file and the Controller follow the usual default patterns (i.e. you specify the controller class in the `fx:controller` attribute)
2. Your FXML file is in the same package as your `JavaApplication3` class. You will need to modify the path passed to `FXMLLoader.load(...)` if this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you dont understandt the flow of JavaFX.

You only can have one Application.

In your case i guess the **JavaApplication3.java**.

Let this class extend javafx.application.Application and call in its main Application.launch(JavaApplication3.class);

In the start Method in your JavaApplication3 you need to Call the **FXMLLoader** to load your **FXML.fxml** and create your **FXMLController.java**

Take a look at here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm